# agora.io screen-sharing web sdk getDisplayMedia

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, video-streaming, live

I'm using Agora to create screen-sharing action and I'm stuck not being able to get it to work on Safari/MacOS. The code below is working for Chrome and Firefox in both Mac/Windows. Every time I click on this `IconButton`, the error message is in the screenshot below.

What could be the issue? I've compared this to Agora's sample code, but cannot figure what caused this bug.

```
<IconButton color='primary' onClick={shareScreenClient ? clearScreenStream : startScreenStream}>
{shareScreenClient ? <StopScreenShareOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' /> : <ScreenShareOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' />}</IconButton>
```

//here's the def of startScreenStream.

```
const startScreenStream = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        screenClient.current = AgoraRTC.createClient(agoraClientObj);

        const channel = classroom;
        const token = null;
        screenClient.current.init(appID, () => {
            screenClient.current.join(
                token,
                channel,
                null,
                (screenUid) => {
                    // Create the screen-sharing stream, screenStream.
                    setScreenStreamObj((x) => ({
                        ...x,
                        streamId: screenUid,
                    }));

                    let screenStreamObj = {
                        streamID: screenUid,
                        audio: false,
                        video: false,
                        screen: true,
                        screenAudio: true,
                    };

                    if (audioDeviceId) screenStreamObj.microphoneId = audioDeviceId;
                    if (videoDeviceId) screenStreamObj.cameraId = videoDeviceId;
                    if (isFirefox) screenStreamObj.mediaSource = 'screen';

                    screenStream.current = AgoraRTC.createStream(screenStreamObj);
                    screenStream.current.setScreenProfile('480p_1');
                    screenStream.current.init(
                        () => {
                            screenStream.current.play('screen-share', { fit: 'cover' }, () => {
                                console.log('sharing screen');
                                setShareScreenClient(true);
                            });
                            screenClient.current.publish(screenStream.current, (err) => {
                                console.error('publish failed', err);
                                //clearScreenStream();
                            });
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            screenStream.current = null;
                            setScreenStreamObj({});
                            console.error('could not init stream', err);
                        }
                    );
                },
                (err) => {
                    screenClient.current = null;
                    console.error('Could not join channel', err);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

[image]